# Существует ли в Unity способ отследить нажатие клавиши клавиатуры без использования Update()?

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет, я пытаюсь оптимизировать свою игру и у меня возник такой вопрос. Можно ли в Unity как то отследить нажатия клавиши клавиатуры без Update()? Хоть у меня и не так много функций в нем, но все же можно ли как то оптимизировать? Можно ли считивать клавиши в FixedUpdate()?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Можно ли было проверить самому? Неужели поменять имя метода с `Update` на `FixedUpdate` тяжелее чем пойти с этим вопросом в интернет? К "оптимизации" это вообще не относится.

Answer (score 1):

Можно считывать в FixedUpdate(), но вы должны понимать, FixedUpdate() работает в точный тик времени стандартно если не ошибаюсь 0.02с. И если вы будете использовать Input.GetKey(...) то это будет работать, а если Input.GetKeyDown(...) к примеру, то это будет работать не всегда, а только если попадете в этот интервал.
Отслеживание клавиш можно хоть где, можно и в упдейтах, можно и в коротайнах запустить. Для простого оружия например оч хорошо идет коротайн в этом плане. И проверка и задержка все подряд )